# How do I enable deep-linking in Android?

Tags: android, deep-linking

Both the links are not working "ypcc://test" and "http://ypcc.nl/test".
It should open the app. Now ypcc://test opens the play store.

In my androidManifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "recipe-app://recipes" -->
            <data android:scheme="ypcc"
                android:host="test" />

        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "recipe-app://recipes" -->
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="ypcc.nl"
                android:pathPrefix="/test"/>

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Does anyone know what I missed?

[image]
This is a deep link scanning app. It's giving me this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For URL parsing of http and https to work, you need to be on Marshmallow. The custom scheme works on earlier devices though.  Also, it's **path**, not **pathPrefix**.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "ypcc://test" -->
        <data android:scheme="ypcc"
            android:host="test" />

    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://ypcc.nl/test" -->
        <data android:scheme="http"
            android:host="ypcc.nl"
            android:path="/test"/>

    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

You may want to add `<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">` to the intent filter if you want to be the only handler for the link, but then you'll also need to add a json file to the server.

[Handling App Links - Google Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html)

Comment: This does not explain why "ypcc://test" still opens the play store.

Comment: Try removing the browsable from the custom scheme